# getting googlemaps to accept a local KML file?

Tags: android, uri, google-maps, android-intent

I am trying to get googlemaps to accept a local KML file.

```
final Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/locate.kml"));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

The file is on the SD card, and is a valid kml file. Googlemaps loads up, but says it cannot find the file.

```
final Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=http://www.website.com/locate.kml"));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Works fine. geo:0,0?q= seems to be very under documented, can anyone help me out with how to use it to refer to a local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you try to open a URL using google maps, the application sends a search request to google using the url you provided. 
Then google servers get the data from the url you have provided and return the result.

Since google servers cannot access urls like 'file://' or anything local like 'http://localhost' you get an error.
That is the reason the second command works, google servers can access http://www.website.com/locate.kml

Comment: Yeap, gotta be a file on a publicly accessible web server. The Google Maps FAQ agrees: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#intranet_kml

Answer (score 0):

It seems it can't be done until Android 2.1

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2454

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript runs in a Sandbox, so it is not able to access local files without proprietary extensions.

Comment: This is on an Android device, not embedded in a web page.

Comment: okay, sry. What is the value of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()?

Comment: /sdcard

I am writing the file from another bit of code;


     File kmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "locate.kml");

And the intent does launch google maps, it just says "Not found file:///sdcard/locate.kml